# MS SQL Server 2008 connection issue

Tags: mysql, linux, sql-server-2008, mysql-workbench

I have a Linux server and a database server (MSSQL 2008) at another location. I use the MySQL ODBC connector to connect to the MS server, but the connection fails every time. I also changed the bind address of my MySQL server to my IP address.

Comment: SQL server != mysql you know that?

Comment: @RC. I know that but we can access sql data into mysql database.

Comment: https://dbperf.wordpress.com/2010/07/22/link-mysql-to-ms-sql-server2008/ I have using this blog

Comment: Essential info missing: what OSes do you use, what WB version, running on which machine? What **exactly** do you use to connect to the MSSQL server. Show your connection settings etc.

Comment: @MikeLischke hello, I have want to connect my php databse to other system with window machine there is .net databased data system, Windows server 2008. I have install mysql odbc tool for connection. I have follow this steps: https://dbperf.wordpress.com/2010/07/22/link-mysql-to-ms-sql-server2008/.

Comment: I don't think what you want is possible. PHP provides a driver for MSSQL, so you can connect directly to it, not involving MySQL at all. If your scenario is that you have your data in a MySQL server and want to have it in MSSQL then migrate it first, then use the MSSQL driver in PHP. This is much better maintainable than what you have in mind with linked servers.